# bbappend patching error for yocto custom receipe

Tags: yocto

I am newbie to yocto. I have create a simple layer and it consist of a simple patch file for wpa_supplicant. I want to modify wpa_supplicant.conf-sane file from my own layer. Original wpa_supplicant resides on different layer

```
wpa-supplicant-bbappend
        ├── wpa-supplicant
        │   └── wiress_info.patch
        └── wpa-supplicant_2.6.bbappend
```

I have generated a diff file

```
 diff -u ../../../poky/meta/recipes-connectivity/wpa-supplicant/wpa-supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf-sane wpa-supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf-sane > wpa-supplicant/wiress_info.patch
```

Here is my patch file :

```
--- ../../../poky/meta/recipes-connectivity/wpa-supplicant/wpa-supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf-sane  2019-04-15 02:47:49.379423777 +0900
+++ wpa-supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf-sane 2019-04-15 03:03:31.765059417 +0900
@@ -3,5 +3,11 @@
 update_config=1

 network={
-        key_mgmt=NONE
+   key_mgmt=NONE
+   ssid="tanmoyc"
+   psk="asdzxcqwe123"
+   proto=RSN
+   key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
+   pairwise=CCMP
+   auth_alg=OPEN
 }
```

Here is my wpa-supplicant_2.6.bbappend file

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}:"
SRC_URI_append = " file://wiress_info.patch "
```

Still I am having some error during patch by yocto

```
Applying patch wiress_info.patch
can't find file to patch at input line 3
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|--- ../../../poky/meta/recipes-connectivity/wpa-supplicant/wpa-supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf-sane 2019-04-15 02:47:49.379423777 +0900
|+++ wpa-supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf-sane    2019-04-15 03:03:31.765059417 +0900
--------------------------
No file to patch.  Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
Patch wiress_info.patch does not apply (enforce with -f)
ERROR: wpa-supplicant-2.6-r0 do_patch: Function failed: patch_do_patch
```

I am not able to figure out whats wrong I am doing? Please help

Comment: You can execute `bitbake -c devshell wpa-supplicant` to instantiate a shell just after do_patch target, so you can create your patch there. It's also easier to just override the entire `wpa_supplicant.conf-sane` file instead of patching it.

Comment: Thank you for your alternate approach it really helpful. @Nayfe

Answer (score 2):

Your patch has wrong source file to patch specified. Thus the message "No file to patch.".

The patches are applied with option `-p1` (see [Patching Code in doc](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#new-recipe-patching-code)) in directory in variable `S` (i.e. unpacked source files, see [Patching in doc](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#patching-dev-environment)).

Although you can apply that patch by adding `striplevel` option in `SRC_URI`, the right way is to fix the patch itself. Please see Nayfe's comment about devshell, it is convenient way to do it (or fix path in your `diff` command).

Comment: Thanks for complete answer (Little typo in answer `Pathcing`).